# How to write into XMM Registers in LLDB

Tags: python, x86, x86-64, sse, lldb

I am trying to read and write values from registers in python using the LLDB API.
For the General Purpose Registers, I have been using the `frame.register['register name'].value` to read and write register values, which works successfully for me.

However, as I approach the Floating Point Registers, I found that this could not be done anymore, as some of the registers, such as the XMM registers do not have a `value` attribute
e.g `frame.register['xmm0'].value` would return `None`.

I have looked into the LLDB API Documentation and I could somehow get the register value using the `frame.register['xmm0'].GetData()`, although it doesn't return a string format like the `value` attribute. 
However, I am still unable to find a way to write into the registers using the LLDB API. I understand that I would be able to do this interactively in CLI using `register write xmm0 "{0x00 0x01 ... 0x0f}"`, as shown in
https://www.mail-archive.com/lldb-dev@lists.llvm.org/msg03228.html, but I would like to be able to do it in python, as I am writing a script in order to perform this task.

So, is there a way for me to write into the XMM registers, or in general, vector type registers using LLDB API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a few days, I finally managed to read and write into the vector registers using the LLDB API.
The XMM Registers has an attribute `summary`, which can also be obtained using `SBValue.GetSummary()`, this attribute returns a string of the values inside the XMM register in the form of `(0x00 0x01 .... 0x0f)` string format.

To modify the XMM Registers, since the XMM registers have no attribute `value`, `lldb.frame.register['register name'].value` would be useless , but there is another way to update registers value, using `lldb.frame.registers[0].GetChildMemberWithName('xmm0').SetValueFromCString(value, self.error)`. The value object has to be a string format, still following the `"{0x00 0x01 ... 0x0f}"` format.