# LLDB: How to write into AArch64 vector registers

Tags: python, arm, lldb, arm64, neon

I am currently using lldb-3.9 on a Raspberry Pi Model 3B, and I am trying to write values into the V-registers in AArch64, but I am having problems with it. 
Using `register read v0`, I'm able to get a result `v0 = {0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f`.

However, when I try to use the exact string to write back into v0 using `register write v0 "{0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f}"`, I received an error message `"error: Failed to write register 'v0' with value "{0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f 0x2f}"`

I have also attached an image depicting the problems I am facing.
[image]

I have used the same method for x86_64 XMM register and it works, but I am puzzled as this does not work for the V-registers in AArch64. This is the related StackOverflow that I have posted regarding the XMM registers. [How to write into XMM Registers in LLDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60389166/how-to-write-into-xmm-registers-in-lldb) .

I would really like to know how I am able to write into the V-registers in AArch64, and possibly a way using the LLDB Python API as well, as im currently using the SetValueFromCString() function for setting the values for vector registers.

Comment: How about `register write v0.16b`?

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE lldb doesnt recognise it as well, it returns `Invalid register name 'v0.16b'`. This is the same for `register write q0, d0, s0` and so on.

Comment: How about `register write q0`?

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE `register write q0` doesnt work as well, even in lldb-9 which I tested. In lldb-9, I'm able to read and write into the D and S registers, but it still doesn't understand Q registers, and writing into V registers shows the same issue here

Comment: Using lldb 14.0.0 your exact command works for me.  Maybe it got fixed in the meantime, but anyway I am voting to close as not reproducible.